# WSO2 API Manager Basic Authentication instead of OAuth

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am searching a way to use Basic Authentication on the API I expose through WSO2 API Manager.

As I could see by default it uses OAuth, and I didn't find a way to choose to use Basic Authentication instead.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box way to secure your APIs with basic authentication in WSO2 API Manager. But you can write a new authentication handler for your requirement.

However please note you need to evaluate the security mechanism and how it is applied via a handler first. For example, when the current handler receives an OAuth2 access token, it knows the user, application, subscription information. That's how it knows how to throttle and publish stats accordingly. You need to be able to find these information from your new handler you introduce for the throttling and stats to work accurately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!